# bash array eval and echo with single and double quotes

Tags: bash

I need to write a script that outputs the first line of an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" >
```

and also echoes the corresponding command. 
In other words I want an equivalent of this:

```
mike@remote:#echo \<?xml version=\"1.0\" \> > file.xml
mike@remote:#cat file.xml
<?xml version="1.0" >
mike@remote:#
```

Here is my script below, but I can't make it work. I do need to use an array, since I have several commands added later on.

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND1='echo \<?xml version=\"1.0\" \> > file.xml'

ARRAY=("$COMMAND1")
for COMMAND in ${ARRAY[@]}; do
        eval $COMMAND
        echo "$COMMAND"
done
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to quote your array expansion to prevent word-splitting.

Comment: Your problem description does not match your script. Please precise what the input and desired output is. Specifically: Is your input the xml file, or the `echo \<?xml version `… thing?

Comment: Sounds vaguely like http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 0):

This is what it should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND1='echo \<?xml version=\"1.0\"\> > file.xml'

ARRAY=("$COMMAND1")
for COMMAND in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
        eval "$COMMAND"
        echo "$COMMAND"
done
```

This will create the `file.xml` file and produce the following output:

```
echo \<?xml version=\"1.0\"\> > file.xml
```

After running the script I ran `cat file.xml` and the output was:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `tee`?  Since you said that you have many commands, are they all going to file.xml?  Not quite sure what your want (perhaps you may want to clarify it) but here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

STRING1='<?xml version="1.0">'

> file.xml
ARRAY=("$STRING1")
for STRING in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
        echo "$STRING" | tee -a file.xml
done
```

`tee -a` keep printing to the console, while appending the output to file.xml.